# xcode ios App "The application could not be verified"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm developing a app with the latest xcode. I configured xcode
to "don't sign" to install the app to my iphone without a developer account.
It was working fine, until i updated my iphone 6 to ios 8.3.

I removed the app from the phone, restarted it, did a "clean"(in Build-Menu),
but same error.

Also i havent changed the project settings in xcode.

Comment: Set the target to run on iOS device, or your phone, then go to project->clean then re run it.

Comment: Define "the latest Xcode" to make this question more useful for current and future readers. What version number?

Comment: today is 29 june 2015 and there is no available update. Im using the latest xcode means im using xcode 6.3.2

Comment: I face the same thing with update XCode 6.4, but after removing the app from the device, it worked, supposed that it had to be because the previous app was build an older version. Something odd indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a no solution for this with this xCode version,
because Apple restrictions.

I installed xcode 7.0 that allows installing apps without developer account to iphones/ipads, solved my problem.